# How to divide divs into columns and wrap and image within

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0

I am attempting to create a profile page that has a number of div's that I need to divide into two columns with an image at the top. I have the image displayed fine but I can't seem to get the information to separate into two columns... at the moment it's all flowing down the page.

Below is my code that I am developing in cakephp:

```
<!--Profile Code-->

<div class="users view large-9 medium-8 columns content">

    <div class="row"> 

        <!--box style-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <!--whitespace around panel-->
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div>
                    <h4 style="color:#00b1b1;"><?= h($user->name) ?></h4>           
                </div>
                <div class="box box-info">

                    <div class="box-body">

                        <div  align="left"><img height="200px" width="200px" alt="Users Picture" src=""> 
                            <input id="profile-image-upload" class="hidden" type="file">
                        </div>                        

                    <div class="col-sm-5">First Name: </div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= h($user->first_name) ?></div>                                                     

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Last Name:</div><div class="col-sm-4"> <?= h($user->last_name) ?></div>                                                      

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Username:</div><div class="col-sm-4"> <?= h($user->username) ?></div>                                

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Email:</div><div class="col-sm-4"> <?= h($user->email) ?></div>                               

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Role:</div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= h($user->role) ?></div>                                

                    <div class="col-sm-5">User ID:</div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></div>                               

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Created:</div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= h($user->created) ?></div>                                

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Modified:</div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= h($user->modified) ?></div>                                

                    <div class="col-sm-5">Active:</div><div class="col-sm-4"><?= $user->active ? __('Yes') : __('No'); ?></div>

                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                <!-- /.box info -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>  
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $('#profile-image1').on('click', function() {
        $('#profile-image-upload').click();
            });
        });       
    </script>
```

Comment: Show me a demo.

Comment: This is what I want it to look like:

    User Name here

    First Name:                         Sammy                                        Profile pic
    Last Name:                         Sample                                         sits here
    Email:                                 sammy@sample.com
    Address:                              somewhere far far away

This is what it looks like at the moment:

    User Name

    Profile Pic

    First Name:
    Sammy
    Last Name:
    Sample
    Email:
    sammy@sample.com
    Address:
    Somewhere far far away